# Doctrine: how to add custom functions that take optional parameter?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Following the official explanation, I want to create my custom MySQL function ROUND() that can take (not mandatory) another second argument.

Sor far I've done this:

```
<?php
namespace HQF\Bundle\PizzasBundle\DQL;

use \Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

class MysqlRound extends FunctionNode
{
    public $simpleArithmeticExpression;

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'ROUND(' . $sqlWalker->walkSimpleArithmeticExpression(
            $this->simpleArithmeticExpression
        ) . ')';
    }

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $lexer = $parser->getLexer();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->simpleArithmeticExpression = $parser->SimpleArithmeticExpression();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

But how to implement the fact that `ROUND(XX)` is ok, and `ROUND(XX, YY)` is ok too?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to declare a second argument, and use the `Lexer` like this:

```php
namespace HQF\Bundle\PizzasBundle\DQL;

use \Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

class MysqlRound extends FunctionNode
{
    private $firstExpression = null;
    private $secondExpression = null;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $lexer = $parser->getLexer();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->firstExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();

        // parse second parameter if available
        if(Lexer::T_COMMA === $lexer->lookahead['type']){
            $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
            $this->secondExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        }

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        // use second parameter if parsed
        if (null !== $this->secondExpression){
            return 'ROUND(' 
                . $this->firstExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker)
                . ', '
                . $this->secondExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker)
                . ')';
        }

        return 'ROUND(' . $this->firstExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ')';
    }
}
```

### Edit

Many Doctrine2 extensions have been written [here](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/tree/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql). All credits to @beberlei for his great work. Many functions are available (`IFELSE`, `IFNULL`, `NULLIF`, `COS`, `ACOS`, etc...) but not all of them (`ROUND`, `GREATEST` or `LEAST` are missing but you can still write them yourself if you need them.)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that bit. Works fine now :)

Comment: Ahah, I was actually doing something very similar today :) Thanks very much for your great edit.

Comment: It would be absolutely perfect with a **`'`** before the ROUND function (last line) **`;)`**

Comment: I'm trying to do the same and base my work on both yours and the official functions like this file: `vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/AST/Functions/LocateFunction.php`

Comment: Based on this article here: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3 I'm trying to implement this in a MySQL query. `Error: Expected known function, got 'COS'`. It seems that DQL doesn't know about ROUND, but also, SIN(), COS()... and RADIANS()... **`(Omg)³²!!`**

Comment: (The problematic Query is: `$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",`)

Comment: That's right! this will save a looot of time: [beberlei/ DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/tree/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql). Either install the extensions or just copy them in the same way you did with ROUND.

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you. Of course I didn't take the whole stuff, I've just took the SQL "functions" part, and I've added them. Now it works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I also found `GREATEST` implementation here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rodgermd/mura-show.com/master/src/Rodger/GalleryBundle/DoctrineExtension/Greatest.php (c) rodgermd@github :

```
namespace Rodger\GalleryBundle\DoctrineExtension;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer,
    Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions;


class Greatest extends Functions\FunctionNode {

  protected $firstExpression, $secondExpression;

  public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
  {
    return sprintf("GREATEST(%s, %s)", 
            $this->firstExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker), 
            $this->secondExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker));
  }

  public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER); // (2)
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS); // (3)
        $this->firstExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary(); // (4)
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA); // (5)
        $this->secondExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary(); // (6)
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS); // (3)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not complete implementation. Greatest is multi arity function and can take any number of arguments not only two.

Comment: Here is complete impl: https://gist.github.com/olimsaidov/4bbd530b1b645ce75e1bbb781b5dd91f